# Monitoring apache storm with monit

Tags: monitoring, apache-storm, monit

I'm trying to find a way to monitor storm topology processes on our supervisor machines with the help of Monit.

I was wondering if someone has managed to do so, or if there's a recommended freeware/open source tool that can achieve such thing.

Basically, we're interested in monitoring the CPU/Memory usage of the different topology processes on the supervisors, and currently use monit to do so for the servers themselves, so I was hoping there might be a way to integrate it into monit, though I'm opened to suggestions.

Thanks in advance, Meny

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with `Monit` but since you said that you are open to suggestions, I would suggest to monitor your Storm via `JMX`. You can use `VisualVM` or `Java Mission Control`. `Java Mission Control` is becoming quickly my favourite tool to monitor my JVM systems.
 Just search the web for how to integrate Storm with JMX and you find a good amount of articles of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using supervisord to achieve the same.

You can refer this link to set it up

http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-multi-node-storm-cluster/#what-is-supervisord